# How to get children of xml element with dart?

Tags: xml, dart, element, children

I would like to have all children of an element.

I have tried following:

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xml/xpath.dart';

final bookshelfXml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document id="doc1">
<line id="1">
<data id="D1" value="20" />
<data id="D2" value="40" />
</line>
<line id="2">
<data id="D1" value="90" />
<data id="D2" value="340" />
</line>
</document>''';


final document = XmlDocument.parse(bookshelfXml);

void main() async {
  var lines = document.findAllElements('document')
      .first.findElements('line')
      .where((line) => line.getAttribute('id') == '1')
      .forEach((e) {print('aaaa $e');});

}
```

The expectation here that I'll have a list of data element which are children of the line with id=1

```
aaaa <data id="D1" value="20"/>
aaaa <data id="D2" value="40"/>
```

but I had:

```
aaaa <line id="1">
<data id="D1" value="20"/>
<data id="D2" value="40"/>
</line>
```

I would like to get all the children of an element (by element's id) in to a list. But for xml  package in dart, I still not find how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll do it.  No need for all that mechanical walking when you have XPath nearby...

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';
import 'package:xml/xpath.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final document = XmlDocument.parse(bookshelfXml);
  final nodes = document.xpath('/document/line[@id="1"]/*');
  for (final node in nodes) {
    print('aaaa $node');
  }
}

const bookshelfXml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document id="doc1">
<line id="1">
<data id="D1" value="20" />
<data id="D2" value="40" />
</line>
<line id="2">
<data id="D1" value="90" />
<data id="D2" value="340" />
</line>
</document>''';
```

which seems to print exactly what you want:

```
aaaa <data id="D1" value="20"/>
aaaa <data id="D2" value="40"/>
```